# Is it possible to buy US sim card at Columbus airport, Ohio

Tags: usa, cellphones, cmh, ohio

I will be traveling to Columbus,Ohio, USA during June for 15days. Is it possible to take a US sim card from Columbus airport Ohio? Or Can I get a sim card outside airport from shops in a reasonable price using the passport. How much is this matrix sim or tsim reliable?

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to *buy* or *obtain* a US sim card at the Columbus OH airport?

Comment: Yes.. If i get from airport itself it is really helpful. is passport and visa enough for that?

Comment: Identification is not required to buy a SIM card in the USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, one may buy a SIM card with cash, a credit card, or a debit card. The shop won't ask to see your passport or visa because that information doesn't have to be reported to anyone. You'll just walk in, make your selection, and pay.

There are far fewer shops selling SIM card at US airports than in overseas ones. The shops exist, but they'll also cost a bit more than if you wait and find a US cell carrier's store in town.

I've never flowed into Columbus. Because it's an international airport (i.e., flights arrive from other countries), it's likely that you'll be able to buy a SIM card there. Edit: here's a screenshot from Google Maps, showing cell phone carrier shops — where you can buy SIM cards — in the Columbus area:

[image]

The map shows several shops just south of the University campus. If you can't find one at the airport, you'll certainly be able to buy one in town.

Source: both [this article](https://toomanyadapters.com/buying-sim-card-usa/) from toomanyadapters.com, and my own experience in decades of domestic and international travel.

Answer (score 1):

I've flown in and out of John Glenn International Airport (CMH) plenty of times. I think the only possible place that might have a sim card is the [Best Buy Express vending machine](https://flycolumbus.com/at-the-airport/restaurants-shops). In a quick search, I haven't been able to determine if one of these vending machines normally has sim cards.

Comment: Thanks.. I am actually going to Ohio State University. Do u know whether i will find near or inside the university.. Is it easy to find shops?

Comment: On the east edge of campus is High St. There's likely to be something there.